# How to use proxys with the electron BrowserWindow function

Tags: javascript, proxy, electron

I have a program that will create a browser window to a specific site, what I need is for each browser window to have a separate proxy. Example proxies entered as so: IP:PORT:USER:PASS,IP:PORT:USER:PASS,IP:PORT:USER:PASS etc... and then it will open as many browser windows as proxys. Here is my current code:

```
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')


let defaultWindow, dimWindow, colorWindow, framelessWindow;
let parentWindow, childWindow;

function createWindows () {

parentWindow = new BrowserWindow({title: 'Parent'});
childWindow = new BrowserWindow({parent: parentWindow, modal: true,show: false, title: 'Child'});
childWindow.loadURL('https://github.com');
childWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  childWindow.show()
});
}

app.on('ready', createWindows);


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

If anyone knows how an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ive worked this one out myself thankfully.

You simply add this into the script:

```
var proxyList = '161.202.226.195:8123'
var url = 'supremenewyork.com'
```

and then replace the old lines of code with this:

```
childWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:`http=foopy,direct://${proxyList}`}, function () {
  childWindow.loadURL(`${url}`);
},
```

yes that is working proxy as of the date this is posted so you may try it yourself if you dont have access to paid proxies :)